# PowerShell accessing variables generated inside scriptblock properly, writing multiple lines into array

Tags: powershell

Below I have an invoke command that executes 2 commands and I want to return their values of:

$user = query user

$osversion = [Environment]::OSVersion

```
    $computer = 'PC1'
    
    $block = {
         $user = query user
         $osversion = [Environment]::OSVersion
       
         $user
         $osversion
    }
    
    $session = New-PSSession $computer
    $invoke = invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $block
    
    $invoke[0]
    $invoke[1]
    $invoke[2]

    #I've also tried dot sourcing it has the exact results see below.
    #. $block
```

**Problem**

I rewrote the results for you, as you can see each array shows one line, but it's not showing the entire users list only the FIRST john.doe, there are multiple other users.

```
$invoke[0] = USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
$invoke[1] = john.doe                                  3  Disc           36  11/30/2022 5:03 PM
$invoke[2] =
PSComputerName : PC1
RunspaceId     : c0a2ae70-060f-45ea-a411-2b6497155e87
Platform       : Win32NT
ServicePack    : 
Version        : 10.0.18363.0
VersionString  : Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0
```

**Problem 2**

. $block also shows everything $block [0,1,2] contains, but again not the missing data from query user

**Question**

How do I properly capture all the contents of query user? Is the two methods I used standard practice? Is it because query user is not a PowerShell command which is holding all the objects right?

Comment: the easiest way to solve this is to return just 1 object with 2 properties from your `Invoke-Command`: `[pscustomobject]@{ user = $user; osversion = $osversion}`

Comment: Any reason you;re using a PSSession rather than just `quser /SERVER:$computer`?